# Shortcut for declaring many variables in Swift

Tags: swift, variables

Is there a more efficient way to write this code considering 12 variables all have the same value.

```
 var b1 = 0,  b2 = 0 , b3 = 0, b4 = 0, b5=0,b6=0,b7=0,b8=0,b9=0,b10=0,b11=0,b12=0
```

Comment: You can create an array with 12 zeroes in it.

Comment: @ShamasS I don't know how to do that could you should with just like b1- b4.

Comment: It would just be something like `var twelveVars : [Int] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,]`. Now you can refer to each one using the index, `twelveVars[0]` or `twelveVars[1]`.

Comment: could i also use that for true/ false statements.

Comment: @JasonStone you can use this to let the compiler infer the element type `var c = Array(repeating: false, count: 10)` or just do it the same way as Paulo suggested `var c = [Bool](repeating: false, count: 10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are okay with using an *array* instead, you might want to use this shortcut:

```
var b = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 12)
```

From [`struct Array`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1641692-init) documentation:

> Creates a new array containing the specified number of a *single*, *repeated* value.

Comment: how would i call this? I cant call b1 or b2 with this.

Comment: You are right! You need to use *array indexes* instead. For instance, `b1` would be `b[0]`, `b2` would be `b[1]`, and so on.